# Why is my single char more than one character long?

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

I'm trying to create a `char*` made of the first character of a string.
The string kept inside a vector of strings.

I have tried the following:

`char* value = &cards[0][0]; cout<<"Value "<<i<<" == "<<value<<endl;`

`char* value = &cards[0].front(); cout<<"Value "<<i<<" == "<<value<<endl;`

('cards' is a vector of strings, each string is a card in a regular 52 card deck)

but whatever I do, *value* is always equal to the entire string.

How do I make *value* a single letter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By convention, a `char*` is interpreted as a null-terminated string literal. So `cout` outputs everything from the character that `value` points to up through the end of the string.

If you just want a single character, you can use `char` instead of `char*`:

```
char value = cards[0][0];
cout << "Value " << i << " == " << value << endl;
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius, a gentleman, and a scholar :D Thanks, it worked!